# Convert numbers toTrue values in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

There is a lot of information how to convert bool values to numbers 1 an 0, but I have not found how to do the opposite conversion:

My DataFrame:

```
col1 col2
1    NaN
2    0.2222
3    NaN
4    4.555
```

Expected output:

```
col1 col2
1    NaN
2    True
3    NaN
4    True
```

Numbers became True values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[~df['col2'].isnull(),'col2']=True
```

Answer (score 2):

Do `mask`

```
df.col2.mask(df.col2.notna(), True, inplace=True)
df
Out[41]: 
   col1  col2
0     1   NaN
1     2  True
2     3   NaN
3     4  True
```